# Cannot insert pandas dataframe to mongo - cannot encode object: array([], dtype=int64), of type: <class 'numpy.ndarray'>

Tags: python, pandas, mongodb, numpy, pymongo

[image]

Here are the first 5 rows of a dataframe `results_df`, that we are trying to insert into an **empty** MongoDB collection using `db['our-empty-collection'].insert_many(results_df.to_dict('records'))`. Presumably because of the last `competitionIds` column, which is an array of ints, we are getting the error: `cannot encode object: array([], dtype=int64), of type: <class 'numpy.ndarray'>`. Some observations:

- The `insert_many` is actually working from my local machine, but failing in our docker container.
- On my local machine, `pymongo.__version__ == '3.10.1'`, and `pd.__version__ == '0.25.3'`
- In the docker container, `pymongo.__version__ == '3.11.1'`, and `pd.__version__ == '0.25.3'`

...so the only difference in library version is that the local machine, where the insert is working, has a slightly older version of `pymongo`. Perhaps there is an issue with the int64 types inside the array?, because Mongo handles nested data just fine and I don't see why an array-column in pandas would cause this issue for the insert?

**Edit:** in Mongo, `competitionIds` is an array of int32 values, so perhaps the `int64` part, rather than the array part, is the issue. Still odd tho to have the local machine / docker container difference.

**Edit2:** upgraded local `pymongo` to 3.11.1 to match the docker container's version, ran `insert_many()` again on my local machine and **it worked again on my local machine**...

**Edit3:** numpy.dnarray (on docker container) vs list (on local machine) seems to be the issue... perhaps an issue then with the python GCP / bigquery library version when querying the data. I've updated the local machine bigquery version to 1.25.0 to match the docker-container's version, however still getting the different types for the `competitionIds` column.

[image]